# docker-compose add data to redis

Tags: redis, docker-compose

I would like to load test data into redis when starting docker-compose. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this.
In docker-compose, the redis service looks like this:

```
redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

I connect via RDM to Redis and can execute the command.

```
hmset payment:test-pay _class com.job.model.Payment id test-pay username user type money timeToExecute 5000
```

But how do load this data to redis during container startup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to persist data between redis runs on your local machine. The best way to do this is to mount a data volume between your containers and your local machine

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    expose:
      - 6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
```

It's that last `volumes:` bit that is key here. That tells docker-compose to take a path on your local machine, `./redis-data`, and put it in the container at `/data`. The redis image that you're using is already configured to save its database to `/data` so you're all set. We can load up some data like so:

```
redis:6379> hmset payment:test-pay _class com.job.model.Payment id test-pay username user type money timeToExecute 5000
OK
redis:6379> save
OK
```

For now we manually call `save` to make sure the database gets persisted to disk, but there's [plenty more to read about redis persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

From here on out, every time you start this docker-compose configuration on this machine, your data will be there.